# Sort object by value - different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object like this:

```
maps = {"08_ruinberg": 1, 
     "63_tundra": 3, 
     "35_steppes": 1, 
     "23_westfeld": 2, 
     "44_north_america": 1}
```

I am generating an output like this:

```
for (var index in empty){
    var output += empty[index]+"x "+index+"<br/>";  
}

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
```

What I want to do is output the names with higher values first (so for example 63_tundra would be first). I wrote this program in PHP first, where I used arsort, but in JS its a little bit harder. I tried several functions from the internetz, but they won't work.

Can somebody help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Why not using the .sort method for Arrays?

Comment: @SanderVisser the object won't change with .sort();

Comment: "What I want to do is output the names with higher values first" you don't want to change the object only output it right?  you can transform your object to an array

Comment: If the duplicate does not answer your your question in some way, feel free to edit your question with what you don't understand and I'll reopen if you ping me.